# How to extend views with shared Layout in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection of views that i want them to share a specific layout.

I created the layout **master.blade.php** ,in a folder i named it layouts.

From the docs , i found that i need to add the tag **@extends** and **section('content')** in my view so it fits under the layout :

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

<div style="background-color:white;width:963px;height:100%">
    <div style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:200px">
        <h2 style="color:sandybrown; text-align:center"><b style="padding-right:40px">Contactez nous</b></h2>
        <br />
        <hr width="50%" color="gris" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:5%">
                <form method="post"  asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RegisterContact" style="padding-left:20px">
                    <label><span style="color:blue">Nom et prenom</span></label>
                    <br />
                    <input size=" 40" style="border-color:darkorange" asp-for="Name"/>
                    <br />


                    <label><span style="color:blue">E-mail</span></label>
                    <br />
                    <input size=" 40" asp-for="Email" style="border-color:darkorange" />
                    <br />
                    <label><span style="color:blue">Message</span></label>
                    <br />
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" style="border-color:darkorange"  asp-for="Message"></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <button style="background-color:blue;"><span style="color:white">ENVOYER</span></button>
                ....
@endsection
```

but when i click in the link in the view's link  in  the navbar , this is what i get  ?:

[image]
so is there a missing part in the logic ?

## Update:

the view and the layout are both under the same folder :

```
   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\layouts
```

the view's name wasn't ending with *.blade.php* , but doing so now i get an exception :

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [layouts.WhoWeAre] not found.
```

this is  the body code of the layout :

```
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light">

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-50">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item navbar1 ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{action('HomeController@WhoWeAre')}}"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Acceuil</B></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item navbar1">
                <a class="nav-link" ><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Qui somme nous</B></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item navbar1">
                <a class="nav-link"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Specialités</B></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/decoupage/nawrass-logo.png " class="rounded-circle bg-light">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-50 ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item navbar2">
                <a class="nav-link" >
                    <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Contactez-nous</B></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item navbar2">
                <img src="images/decoupage/location.png" style="padding-top: 7px">
                <span style="padding-top: 15px">Djerba Houmet Souk</span>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item navbar2">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top: 7px">
                        <img src="images/decoupage/phone.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="font-size: 16px;">
                        <span>75 620 660 </span>
                        <br>
                        <span>98 816 962</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item navbar2">
                <img src="images/decoupage/fb.png" style="padding-top: 7px">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container " style="min-height:100%; padding-left:120px;flex:1;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
    <div style="flex:1;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
         @yield('content')
    </div>
</div>






<div id="footer">
<div class="jumbotron " style="margin-top:0 ; background-color:blue">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card mb-3 " style="background-color: blue">
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">

                            <img src="images/decoupage/logo-white.png" class="card-img" alt="my card image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 ">
                            <div class="card-body ">
                                <p class=" card-text text-white " style="font-size: 14.45px">
                                    Bienvenu a centre de formation ennawres: formation en coiffure hommes et dames Langues {francais, anglais...} ,photographie..et plusieurs d'autres..
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <br/>
                <img src="images/decoupage/phone.png">
                <span class="text-white">
                    75620660-98815952
                </span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img src="images/decoupage/location.png">

                <span class="text-white">
                    Houmet Souk Djerba,1Km Ajim
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4 text-white">
                PROPULSE PAR MOSAIQUE WEB COPYRIGHT 2019
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For information the click in the navbar "Qui sommes nous" link trigger this controller method:

```
public function WhoWeAre()
{
    return view('layouts/WhoWeAre');
}
```

and this is **routes.php** :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
 });

Route::get('/whoweare', 'HomeController@WhoWeAre');
```

Comment: what is the name of this view? does it also have `.blade.php` at the end?

Comment: Hi, what the name of view file, it should be  anyname.blade.php . As it contain blade template @extends and section one, it will only parse if file name contain blade.php

Comment: All layouts are relative to the `resources/views/` folder. Your `master.blade.php` should be in `resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php`. If this doesn't work, please provide more information: (1) the name of the child view and where it is located and (2) your `routes/web.php` for this view.

Comment: Show your `master.blade.php` file..

Comment: Is `WhoWeAre.blade.php` in the `layouts` folder, or does it extend `master`? I think that should be `return view('WhoWeAre');`. You shouldn't directly be returning a `layout` file in any of your controller functions.

Comment: Solved , renaming the view to WhoWerAre.blade.php  i named it before ,after your comments hoWerAre.blad.php which triggered the exception